# Outlook VSTO - What is the win32 hook that I need to intercept when the email subject is changed in the email list preview area?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-object-model

I have an VSTO Outlook Add-in and I am on the need to detect when subject changes on the email list preview area in order to do some stuff at that point. So what win32 hook do I need to attach to?

Comment: "list preview area" - do you mean in the Explorer message list view? Or the reading pane, where the selected message subject and body are displayed? Or in the inline reply editor editor?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko i mean the main explorer message list view. also when i switch the view to "show as conversations", do you know from where is taken the subject from that appears in the explorer message list view? I guess that from the outlook mailitem in the inbox folder, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a particular `MailItem` object, use `MailItem.PropertyChange` event. If you want to monitor all items in a particular  folder, use `Items.ItemAdd/ItemChange/ItemRemove` events (where `Items` collection is returned from `Folder.Items`).

You can see live events and data passed to their handlers in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - for a message, click Item button, go to the Events tab. For a folder, click Folder button, select Items property, click Browse, go to the Events tab.